# Popup for form fields in zend application

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, popup, element

I have created a Zend based php application.

I am looking for a simple way to create a popup or hoover-over help that I can use to to provide user help for the fields that the user should enter.

I guess I need javascript, and for the Zend form elements some decorator. But I have not been able to figure out how it should work. Maybe I need some CSS as well?

Does anyone have an example.

kind regards,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use the jquery plugin for validation, which would prevent the form from submitting until first level checks have been passed. You find further information on the documentation page of jquery. But never trust those checks. You should always validate user input in the backend

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

or you use this, based on jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Info</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(':input.form-input').live('focus', function(){ //get input field
      $(this)
      .closest("div") //get up to div element
      .find(".form-info") //and search for corresponding form-info class to that input field
      .show(); //show it
      }).live('blur', function(){
      //once you leave the input field you might to some things

      //...

      //or just remove the element
      $(this)
      .closest("div") //get up to div element
      .find(".form-info") //and search for corresponding form-info class to that input field
      .hide(); //hide it
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div>
      <input type="text" name="blub" value="" class="form-input" />
      <span class="form-info" style="display:none;">my info to the customer</span>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and as you can see in the example, the css code if fairly simply to adjust to your layout

Comment: I don't think @vmulder's question is about form validation, but more about field description.

Comment: but that might come to the same resolution. Using the form valdation in javascript (here jquery) it is just a matter of timing, when you show the validation text for each field. **After submit button has been clicked**: form validation // **Once a customer enters a form field**: hints for the customers as needed in the question

Comment: Well, this is maybe what you're guessing, but not part of vmurder's question, I'm just saying, no offense here ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your interest in my question.
I am looking for a way to provide information about a field without the user needing to submit the form. More something like hover over, Or having a question mark to raisa a pop up

Comment: if have edited my answer to give you a simple example how to show any info field. still I would advise to use it with any validation engine, so you would save some work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a tool tip for your controls.

Check this out [jQuery Tooltip Plugin Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)

or this [jQuery tools: tool tip](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html)

Comment: yes, this looks great. I will investigate on how to get this in my zend application! thanks a lot.

Comment: @vmulder glad I was of help. Don't forget to accept this answer if it solves your problem ;)